# Actionbar not appearing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I made a project in Android Studio with one of my classmates. The problem is that he added a style and it disappeared. We need to add it again, but we've been trying and couldn't manage to do it (it's our first time using android).

Our AndroidManifest has this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="iuAndroid.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And in our styles.xml file we have this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

I've tried to add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"` inside the activity parameters but it crashes when calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. With this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packet.iuandroid/iuAndroid.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

Thanks!

Edit: forgot to add that the API I'm using is the 23.

Comment: May be you need to clean the code.....Build > Clean Project

Comment: thanks, but still not showing

Comment: "and it disappeared" What disappeared and what do you mean by disappear (in emulator, on device or in Android Studio preview)?

Comment: in all of them. He disabled it because we had to do something and now we can't put it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your styles are fine and don't cause the action bar to hide. Make sure your MainActivity is inheriting `AppCompactActivity`.

Also there's no need to the following item, you can remove it.

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
```

Comment: Thank! Changing the Activities to extend AppCompatActivity instead of Activity solved the problem. This will have any other "effects" to my project?

Comment: @deuseux12 No, actually since Action Bar was introduced in API level 11, `AppCompactActivity` was created later to provide backward compatibility for Action Bar. Generally if your app has Action Bars, so all of your activities should extend `AppCompactActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your Java code.